# Why do I get "Invalid cross-thread access" when using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-8, dispatcher

I am looking into theading to improve my apps performance and am hitting abit of an issue. i am wanting to update the UI from another thread, from what i can gather i should be using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` for this however when i run the below code i get an error about not being able to access the other thread. any ideas?

The error is An `Unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll`

Additional information: Invalid cross-thread access."

```
public void StartPlaneThread()
    {
        var thread = new System.Threading.Thread(DoSomething);
        thread.Start();
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {

        DispatcherTimer TimerTask;
        TimerTask = new DispatcherTimer();
        TimerTask.Tick += new EventHandler(NewPlaneMovement);
        TimerTask.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 10);
        TimerTask.Start();

    }

    int NewPlaneTop;
    int newPlaneBottom;
    int newPlaneLeft;
    int newPlaneRight;

    private void NewPlaneMovement(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            GetUiData() );

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            SetUiData());






        PlaneFlight = PlaneFlight - 1;

        if (PlaneFlight < -10)
        {
            PlaneFlight = -10;
        }
    }

    private void SetUiData()
    {
        double NewTop = Convert.ToDouble(NewPlaneTop - PlaneFlight);
        PlaneObj.Margin = new Thickness(newPlaneLeft, NewTop, newPlaneRight, newPlaneBottom);
    }

    private void GetUiData()
    {
        NewPlaneTop = Convert.ToInt32(PlaneObj.Margin.Top);
        newPlaneBottom = Convert.ToInt32(PlaneObj.Margin.Bottom);
        newPlaneLeft = Convert.ToInt32(PlaneObj.Margin.Left);
        newPlaneRight = Convert.ToInt32(PlaneObj.Margin.Right);
    }
```

Comment: Could you share the exact error you get?

Comment: The Error is " An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll

Additional information: Invalid cross-thread access."

Comment: Well, I think there are a few problems here, though I don't know for sure what's causing that exact error.  For starters, I think DispatcherTimers are intended to be created and fired on the UI thread; yours is being created on a background thread.  Then, after it's created, the background thread immediately exits, so your background thread is gone by the time the timer ticks (which I don't think it can do anyways because it's not on the UI thread).

Answer (score 2):

`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` is used only if you are doing changes which you want to happen on main UI thread i.e. modifying UI at run-time as showing ProgressBar when there is another thread (may be main thread) is going on.

Call `DoSomething` directly without using any thread. Also, call `SetUiData` directly but modify function like this:

```
private void SetUiData()
{
    double NewTop = Convert.ToDouble(NewPlaneTop - PlaneFlight);
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        PlaneObj.Margin = new Thickness(newPlaneLeft, NewTop, newPlaneRight, newPlaneBottom);
    }
}
```

And finally call `GetUiData` directly without `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` and use function as it is as no ui is modified in that function. Hope this helped to clear your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of the `DispatcherTimer` is that you start it in the main thread and it fires in the main thread also. So don't create any threads, just create the DispatcherTimer. You won't need `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` either, since the tick will be in the main thread.